# Autolayout – inconsistent width on iPhone X/11 Devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

Let's say I have constraints that say:

```
photo.leading == view.leading
photo.top == view.top
photo.bottom == view.bottom
photo.width == view.width / 2
```

If the superview's width is 375, you would expect the photo's width to then be 187.5 
However, on iPhone X/11 Devices, I am seeing instead 187.67.

This one discrepancy is causing the scroll-view on the right to misbehave.

### [image]

But again, works fine on the iPhone 6/7/8 – which by the way have the same available width (**375**).

[image]
What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could be facing this issue due to rounding of the decimal places. Pixels are always in multiples of 1x and there can't be 0.5 pixel. So when trying to divide the width by 2 returns a decimal value. You could overcome this by adjusting your `leadingAnchor` by -1 or +1 according to your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

A little tough to tell what's going on... and not really clear what you mean by *"causing the scroll-view on the right to misbehave"... but...

You shouldn't need to *calculate* widths.

- Constrain your `CensioImageView`

  - Top, Leading and Bottom to its superview (`BookQuestionAndAnswerPageView`)
  - Width equal to its superview (`BookQuestionAndAnswerPageView`) with a `0.5` **Multiplier**
- Constrain the scroll view:

  - Trailing to its superview (`BookQuestionAndAnswerPageView`)
  - Leading to `CensioImageView` trailing
  - however you have its Top and Bottom currently set
- Constrain the `UIView` in the scroll view:

  - Top, Bottom, Leading and Trailing to scroll view's `ContentLayoutGuide`
  - Width equal to scroll view's `FrameLayoutGuide`

That should do what you need (I think).

As soon as you start trying to *calculate* sizes, you can run into trouble if you're not handling 2x and 3x display scales.

Comment: The code is already written using constraints against the parent view. See the "self.width = superview.width * 0.5".

Comment: OK - then I guess you need to elaborate on what the problem is.